# Segue to same view controller issue when going back down the navigation stack

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, segue

The cells in my TableViewController are populated from an NSMutableArray property - **itemList**.

```
@interface MenuViewController : UITableViewController <JSONURLConnectionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) JSONURLConnection *jsonConnection;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSURL *jsonURL;   
@property (nonatomic,strong) DataBase *db;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *sel_category;
@property int categoryCount;   
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *itemList;    

@end
```

When the TableViewController is loaded, a method is called to pull a list from my SQLite database.  Once that list is pulled, it's parsed and saved as the NSMutableArray property, the TableView data is reloaded, thus populating the cells dynamically.

Depending on which cell is selected determines what new list is pulled from the sqlite database and then saved to the destination controller's itemList property.

Since the number of segues down the Navigation stack vary and are dependent on what cells are selected, I am reloading the same TableViewController by doing a self segue and carrying over the new NSDictionary property.

[image]

Everything works great when I segue down the stack.  The problem is when I hit the back button to go back up the stack and then try to go back down again.  The issue seems to be with the original properties no longer being accessible when I go back up the navigation stack to a previously loaded view controller. Has anyone else had this problem and know of a solution? I am guessing it's because I need to have a new instance of my TableViewController class passed down the stack more dynamically and I'm not doing it correctly. Here is my segue code:

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSDictionary *item = [self.itemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSData *jsonData = [[item objectForKey:@"child_categories"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *child_categories = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    self.categoryCount  = [child_categories count];
    self.sel_category   = [item objectForKey:@"id"];


    NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"WHERE parent_category_id = %@ ORDER BY name ASC", _sel_category];
    self.itemList = [self.db getItemsFrom:@"product_category" where:sql];

    if ([child_categories count] > 0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
    }
    else if([child_categories count] == 0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
    }
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue1"])
    {
        MenuViewController *mvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        mvc.jsonConnection  = self.jsonConnection;
        mvc.db              = self.db;
        mvc.sel_category    = self.sel_category;
        mvc.categoryCount   = self.categoryCount;
        mvc.itemList        = self.itemList;
        NSLog(@"Segue1");

    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Segue2");
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    //ignore segue from cell since we we are calling manually in didSelectRowAtIndexPath
    return (sender == self);
}
```

Comment: when you go back up the stack, are you simply dismissing the VC?

Comment: I'm just hitting the default back button.

Comment: you could theoretically call another segue to go back up the stack, and pass your properties through prepareForSegue like you've been doing. But it may get a little sloppy :)

Comment: can you call [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; from your back button?

Comment: I guess I could if need, what would that do exactly?

Comment: it should dismiss/pop the topmost modal view.

Comment: @AmitApollo, it appears that kyzer1978 is using pushes and pops to move between controllers, so there is no modal view to dismiss.

Comment: "I am reloading the same TableViewController by doing a self segue" -- I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this, but all segues (other than unwind segues) create new instances of controllers, so you're actually loading a new instance of your table view controller, not the same one.

Comment: The cells are populated by categories. They may (or may not) have child categories so the number of TableViewControllers that I need to segue to is dynamic. The segue is a loop. The idea is to go down the list of categories, child categories etc. (looping through TableView Controllers) until you reach a category with no children and then segue out of the loop to a different view controller. It works great going down the navigation stack but when I go back up and then try to go back down, it fails because the properties don't stay with the previously loaded TableViewController instances.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that "the segue is a loop". You shouldn't go backwards with a segue unless you use an unwind. It's also not clear what properties in which controllers you're saying get lost.

Comment: When you select a cell it's not set up to segue to a different view controller unless the category for that cell has no child categories. Instead it segue's to a new instance of the same TableViewController. Thus looping back to the same View but with different content (the child categories).  The itemList property contains the categories and depending on which cell is selected determines the next itemList property that is passed to the new view (Destination View Controller/same TableViewController).

Comment: You know what, rdelmar, in answering your comment I just figured out what I was doing wrong.  I just needed to create another NSMutableArray property called selectedItemList that is passed to the new view controller object.  I was changing the current itemList property to the child_categories and then passing it to the new VC and wondering why it was different when I went back to that view.   Feeling kind of dumb right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *selectedItemList;**

I needed to add a second property called selectedItemList.

```
@interface MenuViewController : UITableViewController <JSONURLConnectionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) JSONURLConnection *jsonConnection;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSURL *jsonURL;   
@property (nonatomic,strong) DataBase *db;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *sel_category;
@property int categoryCount;   
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *itemList;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *selectedItemList;       

@end
```

The **selectedItemList** is created when a cell is selected instead of changing the current itemList property.

```
NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"WHERE parent_category_id = %@ ORDER BY name ASC", _sel_category];
self.selectedItemList = [self.db getItemsFrom:@"product_category" where:sql];
```

Pass that property to the new TableViewController instead.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue1"])
    {
        MenuViewController *mvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        mvc.jsonConnection  = self.jsonConnection;
        mvc.db              = self.db;
        mvc.sel_category    = self.sel_category;
        mvc.categoryCount   = self.categoryCount;
        mvc.itemList        = self.selectedItemList;
        NSLog(@"Segue1");

    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Segue2");
    }
}
```